# How does the ruby gem dependency resolution work?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, version

I'd like to know how gem handles its dependency resolution.

For example when I want to install the gem foodcritic, it has a dependency on nokogiri in the version 1.5.0.

I unpacked foodcritic-1.6.1.gem but nowhere could I find the strings "1.5.0", "rubygems.org" or whatever could hold the version information.

So how does 'gem' know that foodcritic requires nokogiri-1.5.0?

I ask this because I want to change that dependency manually. Thanks

Edit: foodcritic-1.6.1 holds no gemfile or gemspec file. You can find it under http://rubygems.org/gems/foodcritic

Comment: So I just learned that 'gem' looks into the remote gemspec file at upstream. Is that true? How does it find out where upstream actually is? I could not find the information in the gem file itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the gemspec.  See https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/blob/master/foodcritic.gemspec

```
...
s.add_dependency('nokogiri', '= 1.5.0')
...
```

edit... It is in the gem file... if you extract it you'll see metadata.gz.  That contains the gemspec information...\

```
$ ll
total 56
-rw-r--r--@ 1 philip  staff  28160 Nov 13 12:54 foodcritic-1.6.1.gem
philip@Philips-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads
$ file foodcritic-1.6.1.gem 
foodcritic-1.6.1.gem: POSIX tar archive
philip@Philips-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads
$ tar xvf foodcritic-1.6.1.gem 
x data.tar.gz
x metadata.gz
philip@Philips-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads
$ zmore metadata.gz 
------> metadata.gz <------
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
name: foodcritic
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
  version: 1.6.1
  prerelease: 
platform: ruby
authors:
- Andrew Crump
autorequire: 
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []
date: 2012-08-30 00:00:00.000000000 Z
dependencies:
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: gherkin
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 2.11.1
  type: :runtime
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 2.11.1
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: gist
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 3.1.0
  type: :runtime
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 3.1.0
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: nokogiri
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
philip@Philips-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads
```

Comment: I solved my problem, but I am still curious how this works. There is no metadata.gz in the gem file.

Comment: I unpacked the gem with 'gem unpack foodcritic-1.6.1.gem'. I wasn't even aware that I could also use tar, and that the results would be different. Thanks for  pointing me to it!